# replace regex variable with string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a situation where I have a regular expression like this

```
regex_string = r'(?P<x>\d+)\s(?P<y>\w+)'
r = re.compile(regex_string)
```

and, before I start matching things with it, I'd like to replace the regex group named `x` with a particular value, say 2014. This way, when I search for matches to this regular expression, we will only find things that have `x=2014`. What is the best way to approach this issue?

The challenge here is that both the original regular expression `regex_string` and the arbitrary replacement value `x=2014` are specified by an end user. In my head, the ideal thing would be to have a function like `replace_regex`:

```
r = re.compile(regex_string)
r = replace_regex_variables(r, x=2014)
for match in r.finditer(really_big_string):
    do_something_with_each_match(match)
```

I'm open to any solution, but specifically interested in understanding if its possible to do this **without** checking matches after they are returned by `finditer` to take advantage of `re`'s performance. In other words, **preferrably NOT this**:

```
r = re.compile(regex_string)
for match in r.finditer(really_big_string):
    if r.groupdict()['x'] == 2014:
        do_sometehing_with_each_match(match)
```

Comment: Not without re-building the regular expression pattern itself, no. That requires parsing the string pattern, replacing the group with the literal text it must match, recompiling the pattern and returning that.

Comment: It'll be **much easier** to just verify that `r.group('x')` is equal to `'2014'`. The parsing will have to take into account nested groups, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Recompiling the regular expression is totally fine by me. Any suggestions on how to replace the original variable in the regex string with values in a smart way?

Comment: Care to limit this to a *subset* of regex? Can the pattern match literal parenthesis, question marks and angle brackets, for example? Can there be *nested* groups?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The pattern for all intensive purposes could match anything, but I think it is safe to assume that there will *not* be nested groups.

Comment: Well, with allowing for nested parenthesis (literal or otherwise) you still need a full-blown parser to determine what is part of the pattern and what is actually the closing parenthesis of the group. That's the problem here; you cannot use a regular expression to process your regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this, don't you?

```
r = r'(?P<x>%(x)s)\s(?P<y>\w+)'
r = re.compile(r % {x: 2014})
for match in r.finditer(really_big_string):
    do_something_with_each_match(match)
```

Comment: No, the OP wants to be able to use the original pattern still too, and/or do the same to an *arbitrary number of named patterns*.

Comment: Nice idea, but as @MartijnPieters mentioned, the regex is provided by an end user and, separately, so is the x=2014 bit. I don't know a priori which parts of the regex will be matched. I'll clarify that in the question.